# kotlin, how to return class type from a function

Tags: class, kotlin, retrofit2

having a base class A,  and the class B and C both extend from A

in A it has function to create a retrofit service, which takes a class type as pram:

```
protected fun <T> createRemoteService(clazz: Class<T>, baseUrl: String): T {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(createGson()))
        .build()
        .create(clazz)
}
```

and in class B and C,  the service could be created as (with IBService::class.java or ICService::class.java passed in respectively):

in B:

```
var remoteServ: IBService
init {
    remoteApi = createRemoteService(IBService::class.java, getBaseUrl())
}
```

and in C:

```
var remoteServ: ICService
init {
    remoteApi = createRemoteService(ICService::class.java, getBaseUrl())
}
```

it is ok to pass `IBService::class.java` as the `Class<T>`

would like to have a abstract function in base A to return the class type

```
abstract fun<T> getRemoteServiceClassType() : Class<T>
```

so it could be done in base  A  to create the service by getting the class type

```
remoteServ: Any = createRemoteApi(getRemoteServiceClassType(), getBaseUrl())
```

and implementation in class B  (got error):

```
override fun<T> getRemoteServiceClassType() : Class<T> {
    return IBService::class.java  //<=== got compiler error “Type inference 
                                  // failed. Expected type mismatch: required Class<T>
                                  // found Class<IBService>
}

interface IBService {
    @GET
    fun getRemoteData(@Url url: String,
                  @HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>,
                  @QueryMap params: Map<String, String>?): 
        Call<BResponseData>

}
```

why cant return `IBService::java.class` for the `Class<T>`,   but passing `IBService::class.java` to a function where requires a `Class<T>` is ok?

Comment: `override fun<T> getRemoteServiceClassType() : Class<T> {` What this function definition says that function does is that you can ask for `Class<T>` for _any_ `T`, not some `T` that `IBService` picks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "correct" signature for `getRemoteServiceClassType` is

```
abstract fun getRemoteServiceClassType() : Class<*>
```

if any class at all can be returned, or

```
abstract fun getRemoteServiceClassType() : Class<out SuperType>
```

if all services should have a common supertype. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html for explanation.